# Refresh uploads images in code igniter without hitting upload button

Tags: image, codeigniter, upload, refresh

The image uploads and creates a thumbnail but whenever I refresh the page, the image last uploaded is uploaded again without me hitting the upload button. I don't know if it has something to do with this code

```
if ($this->input->post('upload')) {
$this->Gallery_model->do_upload();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It will request a new upload each time it finds $_POST['upload'];